# Oracle SQL: Self-Reference table hierarchy. How to add parents after selection up to top with temp table/loop?

Tags: oracle

- I have a table Jobmst, that has a primary key of jobmst_id, and a parent through self-reference of jobmst_prntid.
- So in effect the parents become groups for jobs or other groups, since you can nest many levels deep.
- I am trying to identify when there are multiple calendars (evntmst_ids) for a given parent.
- But, later if they are say at level 3 in the hierarchy depth, I want to add level 2 and level 1 back in via another unlisted CTE, via a process of re-constituting jobmst_ids.
- To do this, I have tried to use a temp table of sorts called jids. The idea was to add all the jobmst_ids for children of the parent ids repeatedly until the count of the number of records in the temp table remained constant, at which point all the parents of parents of parents etc would have been added.

But, I keep getting this for jids:

---

PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

[image: ORA-00942]

**Is there some sort of context that is making jids invisible?

How would I go about modifying the code to fix this?

Advice much appreciated.**

---

```
declare
 cnt number;
 lastcnt number;
begin
with cals_in_group(jobmst_prntid, evntmst_id, cal_count) AS
(
  select jobmst_prntid, evntmst_id, count(1)
  from jobmst
  group by jobmst_prntid, evntmst_id
  order by jobmst_prntid, evntmst_id
),
group_stats_gt_1(jobmst_prntid, tot_job_in_group, num_cal_in_group) AS
(
  select jobmst_prntid, sum(cal_count) , count(1)
  from cals_in_group
  having count(1) > 1
  group by jobmst_prntid
  order by jobmst_prntid
),
/*
select num_cal_in_group, jobmst_prntid
from group_stats_gt_1
order by num_cal_in_group,jobmst_prntid
*/
jids(jobmst_id) AS
(
 select jobmst_prntid from group_stats_gt_1
)
--select jobmst_id from jids;

 select count(1)
 into cnt
 from jids;
 lastcnt := -1;
 WHILE cnt <> lastcnt
 LOOP
   lastcnt := cnt;
   insert into jids
    select jobmst_id 
    from jobmst 
    where jobmst_prntid in(select jobmst_id from jids)
    and   jobmst_id not in(select jobmst_id from jids);
  select count(1)
  into cnt
  from jids;
 END LOOP;
 select count(1) from jids;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

> To do this, I have tried to use a temp table of sorts called jids

If `jids` is a CTE, this:

```
jids(jobmst_id) AS
(
 select jobmst_prntid from group_stats_gt_1
)
```

then it won't work. You can't insert anything into it.

If it has to be a true temporary table, then create a global temporary table (or private, depending on Oracle version you use).

Something like this:

```
SQL> create global temporary table gtt_jids (jobmst_id number)
  2  on commit preserve rows;

Table created.

SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select empno from emp where deptno = 10) loop
  3      insert into gtt_jids values (cur_r.empno);
  4    end loop;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from gtt_jids;

 JOBMST_ID
----------
      7782
      7839
      7934

SQL>
```

Apart from Oracle documentation, have a look at [Global Temporary Tables](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables) @ORACLE-BASE which has everything at the same place, with examples.

Comment: Ok. Can you elucidate. on last point please. A link to an example perhaps?

Comment: Sure. I posted a short example; have a look, please.

Comment: Thanks. Will give that a try.

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get that to work with the declared variables to store counts.

Comment: If you could create a test case (for example, using Scott's EMP and/or DEPT tables) and post what you tried, perhaps we'll be able to assist. Or - post what you managed to do so far, let us see it. Maybe it is something *obvious*.